# Perform sudo commands via midnight commander and sftp

Tags: ssh, sudo, sftp, vps, mc

I use midnight commander to sftp into my ubuntu VPS.

The VPS requires sudo for anything important, e.g. copy/move/delete files. So for e.g. I cannot press <kbd>F5</kbd> to copy (except into `~`).

Is it possible for mc to ask for user elevation / send `sudo` when needed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. I don't know `mc` internals but generally you must call `sftp-server` on remote host via `sudo`. There are two ways to do it, on client or on server. On client you have to know how `mc` calls `sftp` and to modify how `mc` calls it. It's easier on the server where you can force it via `ForceCommand`. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/637624/330987

Change on client (`sudo` on remote host is configured)

FYI, one cannot use `RemoteCommand` option, `sftp` fails with error `Cannot execute command-line and remote command.` (because in the background `sftp` calls `ssh ... -oRemoteCommand="/usr/bin/sudo /usr/libexec/sftp-server" ... -- localhost sftp` and *sftp* in the end of the background command seems to conflict with *RemoteCommand* option)

```
sftp -b - -s '/usr/bin/sudo /usr/libexec/sftp-server'
```

But as it is not clear how `mc` uses SFTP, I would recommend to go to server-side approach (see below).

Change on server

```
LogLevel DEBUG3
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes
PrintMotd no
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/sftp-server
Match User <mc user>
        X11Forwarding no
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        PermitTTY no
        ForceCommand /usr/bin/sudo /usr/libexec/sftp-server
```

Comment: Thanks, however that wouldn't solve the permissions problem - it would create a sudo connection to the remote, but would still ssh into remote as a non-priviledged user. So once connected, I'd still get permissions problems. The idea is to elevate permissions on case-by-case basis, within mc. I'm not sure if that's possible. BTW downvote is not mine, thanks for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: I think you didn't get it. If you run `/usr/bin/sudo /usr/libexec/sftp-server` on remote host it means you run `sftp-server` with `root` permissions. So you have access to all files on remote host. I know how it works, I was doing backups via `rsnapshot` via SFTP of remote hosts, in the background `rsnapshot` was calling `sudo /usr/libexec/sftp-server`.

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/jirib/7a37a1ccfcbd3a4dbe802997214ec4d3

Comment: That means `sudo` is not local but remote.

Comment: The idea is to use mc. In the shell I'd have no problems.

Comment: Here you have server-side force privileged sftp-server https://gist.github.com/jirib/7a37a1ccfcbd3a4dbe802997214ec4d3#file-gistfile2-txt